# How to change the look of overdue dates with flutter CupertinoDatePicker?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I don't know how to change the grey color of overdue dates. For me there is not enough contrast between past date, future date and today's date.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b8f7f1f986/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/date_picker.dart#L224) of of `CupertinoDatePicker`, it seems that the colors are not easily changeable.

To quote from flutter's source code:

```dart
TextStyle _themeTextStyle(BuildContext context, { bool isValid = true }) {
  final TextStyle style = CupertinoTheme.of(context).textTheme.dateTimePickerTextStyle;
  return isValid
    ? style.copyWith(color: CupertinoDynamicColor.maybeResolve(style.color, context))
    : style.copyWith(color: CupertinoDynamicColor.resolve(CupertinoColors.inactiveGray, context));
}
```

Therefore, the only direct impact you have on the colors is by wrapping your CupertinoDatePicker inside a `CupertinoTheme` and providing a value for `textTheme.dateTimePickerTextStyle` . Further customisation is not supported as of yet

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no option to change the overlay color from the `CupertinoDatePicker` widget constructor, you will need to change the overlay color from its source code.

First, we will take an example of `CupertinoDatePicker` like this:

```
      // ...
      child: CupertinoDatePicker(
              onDateTimeChanged: (date) {},
            ),
      // ...
```

And it shows this on the screen:

[image: CupertinoDatePicker]

Going inside its source code, you need to search for those lines:

```
const Widget _startSelectionOverlay = CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(capEndEdge: false);
const Widget _centerSelectionOverlay = CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(capStartEdge: false, capEndEdge: false);
const Widget _endSelectionOverlay = CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(capStartEdge: false);
```

This represents the implementation of that grey overlay that you see on the screen.

Then, you need to go through the `CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay` source code also, you should find this:

```
  /// default margin and use rounded corners on the left and right side of the
  /// rectangular overlay.
  /// Default to true and must not be null.
  const CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay({
    super.key,
    this.background = CupertinoColors.tertiarySystemFill,
    this.capStartEdge = true,
    this.capEndEdge = true,
  }) : assert(background != null),
       assert(capStartEdge != null),
       assert(capEndEdge != null);
```

We want to change the color of that overlay background, so in this line:

this.background = CupertinoColors.tertiarySystemFill,

We will change its value with the `Color` we want, so as an example we will change it like this:

```
this.background = const Color.fromARGB(49, 0, 253, 30),
```

and after a hot restart, the result will be:

[image: CupertinoDatePicker]

**Notes:**

- If you want to use material colors like `Colors.red`,
  `Colors.green`..., you will need to import the material library on
  the top of that file.
- You should mark the color with a `const` as I did in the sample of
  code, otherwise, you will get an error.